# LeetCode 1094. Car Pooling. What is Time Complexity?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

I'm in my interview prep cycle currently and have been ramping up lately. Here's the problem:

[LeetCode 1094](https://leetcode.com/problems/car-pooling/)

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding the time complexity of this question. here's my code:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean carPooling(int[][] trips, int capacity) {
        HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> dropOff = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> pickUp = new HashMap<>();
        
        int endLocation = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < trips.length; i++) {
            int peopleToAdd = trips[i][0];
            
            //get current values from map
            List<Integer> peopleToGet=pickUp.getOrDefault(trips[i][1], new ArrayList<>());
            List<Integer> peopleToDrop=dropOff.getOrDefault(trips[i][2],new ArrayList<>());
            
            //add group to list of people being dropped/added at a stop
            peopleToGet.add(peopleToAdd);
            peopleToDrop.add(peopleToAdd)
            ;
            pickUp.put(trips[i][1], peopleToGet);
            dropOff.put(trips[i][2], peopleToDrop);
            endLocation = Math.max(endLocation, trips[i][2]);
        }
        
        int currentCapacity = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= endLocation; i++) {
            if (pickUp.containsKey(i)) {
                List<Integer> key = pickUp.get(i);
                for (int temp : key) {
                    currentCapacity += temp;
                }
            }
            if (dropOff.containsKey(i)) {
                List<Integer> key = dropOff.get(i);
                for (int temp : key) {
                    currentCapacity -= temp;
                }
            }
            
            if (currentCapacity > capacity) return false;
        }
        
        return true;
        
        
    }
}
```

the nested for-lop always makes me think n^2, but if you think about the question, each cohort has a pickup and a drop-off. so, You're really making 2N computations where N is the number of cohorts. You're also iterating through all potential stops.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess your time complexity would be `O(N ^ 2)`:

- `O(N)` for the loop

  - `O(N)` for the `Math.max()`

I may be wrong though.

---

We can use `TreeMap`, which has an `O(Log N)` get method and reduce the time complexity to O(N Log N) and the memory complexity would be `O(N)`:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean carPooling(int[][] trips, int capacity) {
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> treemap = new TreeMap<>();

        for (int[] trip : trips) {
            treemap.put(trip[1], treemap.getOrDefault(trip[1], 0) + trip[0]);
            treemap.put(trip[2], treemap.getOrDefault(trip[2], 0) - trip[0]);
        }

        for (int passenger : treemap.values()) {
            capacity -= passenger;

            if (capacity < 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Asymptotically, it does not matter if you would loop through your array once or a billion times, both are order of N time complexity:

```
O(10 * e9 N) == O(N)
```

---

Your code looks pretty good, not bad at all. Just make sure to:

- Keep your spacing consistent
- Write everything in a separate line
- Always add `{}`, even if it is not required for single line `if` or `for`.

```
class Solution {
    public boolean carPooling(int[][] trips, int capacity) {
        HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> dropOff = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> pickUp = new HashMap<>();

        int endLocation = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < trips.length; i++) {
            int peopleToAdd = trips[i][0];

            //get current values from map
            List<Integer> peopleToGet = pickUp.getOrDefault(trips[i][1], new ArrayList<>());
            List<Integer> peopleToDrop = dropOff.getOrDefault(trips[i][2], new ArrayList<>());

            //add group to list of people being dropped/added at a stop
            peopleToGet.add(peopleToAdd);
            peopleToDrop.add(peopleToAdd);
            pickUp.put(trips[i][1], peopleToGet);
            dropOff.put(trips[i][2], peopleToDrop);
            endLocation = Math.max(endLocation, trips[i][2]);
        }

        int currentCapacity = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= endLocation; i++) {
            if (pickUp.containsKey(i)) {
                List<Integer> key = pickUp.get(i);

                for (int temp : key) {
                    currentCapacity += temp;
                }
            }

            if (dropOff.containsKey(i)) {
                List<Integer> key = dropOff.get(i);

                for (int temp : key) {
                    currentCapacity -= temp;
                }
            }

            if (currentCapacity > capacity) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;

    }
}
```

#### Good luck in your interviews!!

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/car-pooling/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions, explanations, efficient algorithms with a variety of languages, and time/space complexity analysis in there.

Comment: I Appreciate the response. Did you write the code in your response?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution {
    public boolean carPooling(int[][] trips, int capacity) {
         TreeMap<Integer, Integer> treemap = new TreeMap<>();

         for (int[] trip : trips) {
             treemap.put(trip[1], treemap.getOrDefault(trip[1], 0) + trip[0]);
             treemap.put(trip[2], treemap.getOrDefault(trip[2], 0) - trip[0]);
         }

         for (int passenger : treemap.values()) {
             capacity -= passenger;

             if (capacity < 0) {
                 return false;
             }
         }

         return true;
    }
}
```

Try this code using Java format you will pass..